# How to check if a XAML element supports AutomationId attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a way to check that every WPF control in my codebase has an AutomationProperties.AutomationId attribute.  (This is needed for automated UI testing.)  I also need to make sure this requirement is enforced in the future on all future forms which may be added to the codebase.  I have thought through a few different approaches, and so far none of them seem like the right approach.

Option 1: Write unit tests for every WPF form in the application.

This is a fairly easy approach.  I have already written a method which checks all the logical descendants of a DependencyControl and makes sure each descendant has an AutomationId. Here's some C#:

```
    private bool AllControlsHaveAutomationId(DependencyObject control)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (this.ControlHasAutomationId(control))
        {
            foreach (object o in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(control))
            {
                FrameworkElement frameworkElement = o as FrameworkElement;
                if (frameworkElement != null)
                {
                    result = this.AllControlsHaveAutomationId(frameworkElement);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private bool ControlHasAutomationId(DependencyObject control)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId(control));
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that I would be assuming that other developers would write unit tests for their forms, which is not a good assumption.  If I can't assume that AutomationIds will be added to all WPF controls, then I can't assume that the unit tests will be written, either.

Option 2: Read each XAML file using System.Xml.XmlDocument.  Check the elements in the document for AutomationProperties.AutomationId.

This approach seems promising.  My original plan was to load each XAML file into an XmlDocument and check the AutomationProperties.AutomationId attribute for each element in the document.  However, I realized that not every element type in XAML supports the AutomationProperties.AutomationId attribute.  What I need is a way to read an element in a XAML file and determine if the element supports the AutomationProperties.AutomationId attribute.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a note: If you're testing via the UI, it's not a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the BAML (compiled XAML) in all of the assemblies of your codebase....there are various ways to do that.

### Looking at BAML via .NET Reflector and an AddIn

One way of doing that would be to write a Reflector add-in.

You could perhaps base it off the BAML Viewer which is already available.

- http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer&referringTitle=Home
- http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/baml/

Then hopefully it would just be a case of giving reflector your assemblies and saying find me things without Automation IDs.

### Looking at BAML via StylesExplorer

- http://stylesexplorer.codeplex.com/

Allows you to access the BAML in an assembly with a `BamlAssembly` class.

### Looking at BAML via LocBAML

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx
- http://bloc.codeplex.com/releases/view/44124 (related link)

The source code to the tool is available in the Windows SDK. You could modify to look for the automation properties instead of localizable ones.

### Using XamlReader.Load()

You might even get somewhere with just `XamlReader.Load()` on its own with your uncompiled .xaml files.

- http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/xamlreaderloadbaml-removed-125290.aspx

### Using XamlReader.LoadBaml()

- http://wpftutorial.net/baml.html

### Other Options

A runtime verifier of various Automation

- http://acccheck.codeplex.com/releases/view/46527